# Visual Studio crashing when using IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, .net-4.0, ivalueconverter

I have a class that implements IValueConverter.  Every time I build build my solution, visual studio crashes right after the build is successful.

```
public class BoolToEditOrCreateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object();
    }
}
```

> Visual Studio problem details:
>
> Problem signature:   Problem Event
>   Name: APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: devenv.exe   Application
>   Version:  10.0.30319.1   Application
>   Timestamp:    4ba1fab3   Fault Module
>   Name: clr.dll   Fault Module
>   Version:  4.0.30319.1   Fault Module
>   Timestamp:    4ba1d9ef   Exception
>   Code: c00000fd   Exception
>   Offset:   000018d7   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
>   Locale ID:    1033
>
> ```
> Additional information about the problem:   LCID: 1033
>
> Read our privacy statement online:   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy
> ```
>
> statement offline:
>   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Then I must remove the entire class from the project to keep visual studio from crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft just released SP1 for Visual Studio 2010, which supposedly fixes a bunch of crash issues. I don't know if it will solve your problem, but it certainly won't hurt to try.

Here is the download link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en

And here is the associated KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509

Hope this helps!

Comment: Visual Studio stopped crashing after I installed the SP1 update.  Thanks.